# JS function does not change the color of the HTML text if it is repeated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I struggled to select a title for this question, but I will do my best to explain below.

I have this checker made, that checks words from input one by one and if the word input correctly - it changes the color to green. It does it by splitting input into separate words and place it in the array.

What I see though is that if there is a repeatitive word in the text that I am comparing input words against, it does not change the color.
Why would that be? The way I see my function of changing the color takes words' position in the array, not its value, and then simply adds the color for an html element.

```js
let text = document.querySelector('.card-body').innerHTML;
let splitText = text.split(' ');

let userInput = document.querySelector('.form-control');
userInput.addEventListener('input', acceptInput)

let correctWords = [];
let mistakes = 0;
let words = [];


function acceptInput() {
    userInput.onkeydown = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            words = userInput.value.split(' ');        
            console.log(words); 
            console.log(splitText);
            let position = words.length-1;
            compareWordsArrays(position);
        }
    }
}

function compareWordsArrays(position) {
    
    for(i = position; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(words[i] === splitText[i]) {
            console.log(`Correct word detected: ${words[i]}`);
            let wordIndex = words.indexOf(words[i]);
            changeColor(wordIndex);

        } else {
            console.log('Incorrect word;');
            mistakes += 1;
            console.log(mistakes);
            
        }
    }
    
}

function changeColor(pos) {
    splitText[pos]="<font color=green>"+splitText[pos]+"</font>";
    let c = splitText.join(' ');
    document.querySelector('.card-body').innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">Random text that appears from some generator or some stuff. But it needs to have quite few text, actually.
     </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

In my example you can see word "some" repest twice in the sentence, and second word "some" is not being changed
though it does not count second word as a mistake neither
I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: `words.indexOf(words[i])` makes no sense... you're trying to get the index of a word for which you already have the index "i". And this is probably the line causing you the trouble as indexOf returns the index of the first occurence, so if you have the same word twice in the array, it will only ever return the index of the first one. What I would do is remove that whole line and just do `changeColor(i);` on the next one... that should I think do the trick

Comment: Oh yes! True! Thank you very much, it helped. I got lost in my own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
if(words[i] === splitText[i]) {
        console.log(`Correct word detected: ${words[i]}`);
        let wordIndex = words.indexOf(words[i]);
        changeColor(wordIndex);

    }
```

To

```
if(words[i] === splitText[i]) {
        console.log(`Correct word detected: ${words[i]}`);
        changeColor(i);

    }
```

As:

- There's no point looking for an index you already know (`i` in this case)
- indexOf only returns the first occurence index, hence your script working only for the first occurence...

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` will give you the first index a value appears in.

So if your array contains duplicate words, you will find the index of the first time the word was found instead of the index of the duplicate.

Luckily arrays have the `.lastIndexOf()` method as well.

Change `let wordIndex = words.indexOf(words[i]);` into `let wordIndex = words.lastIndexOf(words[i]);` and it works in the pen.

Comment: This won't answer the question properly... now instead of changing only the first occurence it will change only the last one...

Comment: @LaurentS. Why would the first occurrence need changing again? It's already green from the previous time `acceptInput()` was triggered. That would only matter if there's a color change in the `else` as well or if the `splitText` array get cleared.